# Bit as a p.p. form of bite (v)

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, tenses, verb-forms

The Merriam-Webster dictionary lists *bit* as an alternative past participle form of the verb *bite*, with *bitten*.

> **bite** (1 of 2) (verb) (*ˈbīt*); **bit** (*ˈbit*); **bitten** (*ˈbi-tᵊn*) also **bit**; **biting**

As far as I know, no other dictionary lists *bit* in this form. Is this an archaic form, or is there more to it? Detailed explanations are welcome.

Comment: "The Biter Bit" goes back to at least the Wilkie Collins story of that name, before 1900

Comment: I agree with alphabet that it's *informal* (and/or "uneducated"), not "archaic". @JimMack - there are plenty of written references to ***The biter bit*** back in the early 1700s

Comment: It should be noted that, to a computer nerd, "bit" and "byte" are two different (though related) things.  (And they're both nouns.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Garner’s Modern English Usage*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Garner_s_Modern_English_Usage/ISGUEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22has+bit%22&pg=PA145&printsec=frontcover) has an entry for:

> **bite** > **bit** > **bitten**. So inflected. While *bit*, the past-tense form, is recognized in most dictionaries as an alternative
> past participle, since 1825 or so it has been far less common than the
> standard *bitten*. Although the *OED* labels it as archaic, the
> participle *bit* lives on in some SET
> PHRASES—e.g. . . .

Examples offered include *has bit his lip*, *should have bit his tongue*, and *has bit the dust*.

The entry concludes by noting:

> In most contexts, though, *bitten* is the preferred
> form . . .

Answer (score 1):

According to Ngram, while ["He was bitten" is much more popular than "He was bit,"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+was+bit%2CHe+was+bitten&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) in the get-passive ["He got bit" and "He got bitten" are about equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+got+bit%2CHe+got+bitten&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

This is consistent with *bit* being an informal replacement for *bitten,* since the get-passive is more common in informal contexts. Ngram doesn't suggest a clear historical trend.

Comment: The full OED specifically says ***bit*** as the Past Participle is *archaic*, but I've often used it slightly facetiously (like I might say *I ain't frit*). And many people are familiar with various incarnations of [***The biter bit***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22biter+bit+a+proverbial%22) *- a proverbial phrase meaning that one is caught in one's own trap , that the tables have been turned .* ***The biter bitten*** just doesn't have quite the same ring to it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do think Ngram is correct regarding modern usage. I would typically say "I got bit by a mosquito," not "I got bitten by a mosquito." It doesn't strike me as facetious or even particularly unusual, though it's certainly more informal.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Broadening the search by removing the "He," it seems like [BrE tends to prefer "got bitten"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+bit%2Cgot+bitten&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) whereas [AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+bit%2Cgot+bitten&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) has a slight preference for "got bit."

Comment: I don't have OED access, so I'm not sure if it says anything about how closely connected the modern get-passive use is to the archaic use. For the regular passive, both dialects seem to prefer "bitten."

Comment: The OED's *only* explicit mention of the irregular / archaic / informal use is in the initial "Forms" section, which starts with **Pa. tense bit /bɪt/. Pa. pple. bitten /ˈbɪt(ə)n/; also bit. arch. Forms: inf.** But their usage citations include *1955   Times 11 May 14/6   ‘Better men than Mr. Strachey **have bit the dust** in Dundee,’ was how the Tory hopes were summed up by one Conservative* under section 16 "Phrases".

Comment: I notice you end with *Ngram doesn't suggest a clear historical trend.* But your actual NGrams only go back to 1980 anyway. Why not link to [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+bit%2Cgot+bitten&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), clearly showing that ***got bit*** and ***got bitten*** have remained in lockstep for over two centuries. Where ***was bit / was bitten*** [is completely different.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+bit%2Cwas+bitten&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: with "have/had": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+bit%2Chave+bitten%2Chad+bit%2C+had+bitten&year_start=1819&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Tim — Active and passive together: [have bitten,was bitten,have bit,was bit,got bitten,got bit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+bitten%2Cwas+bitten%2Chave+bit%2Cwas+bit%2Cgot+bitten%2Cgot+bit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)